# Azureで使用できるデビットカードについて

Tags: azure

Azureのサインアップのページに「サインアップには、認証用にクレジット カードまたはデビット カードが必要です。」と記載されています。
運用で使用するために、法人向けのデビットカード作成を検討しているのですが、デビットカードを作成したものの「認証に使えませんでした」というのも困りますので、実績があるところ（会社）のデビットカードにしたいと考えています。
実際に法人向けのデビットカードで認証された方がおりましたら、どこのデビットカードかをお教えいただけると幸いです。または、「ここに使用可能なデビットカード一覧がある」などの情報でも、とても助かります。

Comment: Stack Overflowは技術的な問題を中心としたQ&Aサイトなので、こちらは少し扱いにくい質問ですね。Azureのサポートに問い合わせるのが一番確実だと思います。